# Error MYSQL #error1064 when assign double to Price field?

Tags: mysql-error-1064

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `Menu` CHANGE  `Price`  `Price` DOUBLE( 10 ) NOT NULL

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

Here's the real syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY COLUMN your_column DOUBLE NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY COLUMN your_column DOUBLE NOT NULL;
```